# Find the frequency of number repeates (r-l+1)/2 times in range [l:r]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, frequency

Given the array: `A[N]`. There are some queries including `Li` and `Ri`. We must Find the number that appears more than `(Ri-Li+1)/2` times in range `[Li:Ri]`.

`For example`:
`INPUT:`

> N=7
> 1 1 3 2 3 4 3

`OUTPUT:`

> Ranges:
> [1:3] ans is :>1
> [1:4] no answer
> [1:7] ans is :>3
> [2:7] no answer

First, I think we can use `map` to store the times that `A[i]` appears from `1 to j`
And it's take up a lot of memories if `N` up to `5e5`.

Then I sort(Increasing order) the queries so that `Ri`, and no more idea.

`Suggestions:`

Is there any efficient **algorithm** to this problem or any **data structure** to stores the frequency of `A[i]`: from `1 to j`?

Comment: Appear more than half the time, sounds like one of the algorithms from ["fantastic algorithms and where to find them"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YA-nB2wjVcI) see the part heavy hitters.

Comment: Just use a dictionary to count them.  That's CPU and memory complexity O(Ri-Li).

Comment: Why is [1:7] 3 but [2:7] is no ansver? In the first case (7-1+1)/2=3 but there are only 3 3s so there are not more than 3, in the 2nd case (7-2+1)/2 = 3, still only 3 3s but now there is no answer???

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about such data structure, but I find an solution for this problem.

If `Ri - Li + 1` is odd, there may have two elements appear `(Ri - Li + 1) / 2` times. Which one do you want to get? We can use the algorithm beblow to get one of them and the algorithm can get all of these two if you want.

If there are just few queries satisfy `\sum (Ri - Li)` are small enough, get the answer for each `[Li, Ri]` separately.

For each `[Li, Ri]`,we can use a `O(Ri - Li)` time, `O(1)` auxiliary memory algorithm to get the answer. If there is a x appears exactly `(Ri - Li + 1) / 2 times`, at least one of three case below must happend (suppose `Ri > Li`).

1. x appears `(Ri - Li + 1) / 2` times in `[Li, Ri - 1]`.
2. x appears `(Ri - Li + 1) / 2` times in `[Li + 1, Ri]`.
3. `A[Li] == A[Ri] == x`.

For case 1,2 we can use '[Heavy Hitters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YA-nB2wjVcI)'  algorithm  to find the candidate x.

So can get three candidate x for one travese, and check each of them to find the answer(see cpp code below).

```cpp
int getCandidateX(int L, int R) {
    int x = A[L], count = 1;
    
    for(int i = L + 1; i <= R; ++i){
        if(A[i] == x) ++count;
        else if(--count == 0){
           x = A[i];
           count = 1;
        }
    }

    return x;
}

int getFrequency(int L, int R, int x) {
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = L; i <= R; ++i) {
        if(A[i] == x) ++count;
    }
    return count;
}

/** 
 * if Ri == Li, no answer
 * suppose Ri > Li
 * return {x, 0} and {-1,-1} if no such element
 */ 
pair<int,int> getAnswer(int Li, int Ri) {
    int t = (Ri - Li + 1) / 2;
    int x;
    if((Ri - Li) & 1) {
        x = getCandidateX(Li, Ri);
        if(getFrequency(Li, Ri, x) == t) return {x, 0};
        return {-1, -1}
    }

    x = getCandidateX(Li, Ri - 1);
    
    if(getFrequency(Li, Ri, x) == t) return {x, 0};
    x = getCandidateX(Li + 1, Ri);
    if(getFrequency(Li, Ri, x) == t) return {x, 0};
    if(A[Li] == A[Ri] && getFrequency(Li, Ri, A[Li]) == t) 
        return {Li, 0};
    
    return {-1,-1}
}
```

When `\sum (Ri - Li)` is large, I found an `O((m + n)logn)` online solution, but it also cost a lot of memory. I conduct it as a RMQ(Range Maximum Query) problem and solve it by ST(sparse table) algorithm.

First, we can get the frequency in `[L, R]` of any `x` with `O(logn)` time.

We can store all the position of `x` in `map[x]` where map maps x to its position array.(we can use treemap or hashmap)

Then we can get the frequency of `x` in `[L, R]` by binary search which cost `O(logn)` time.

Define `num[L][R]` be a set of elements appear more than `(R - L + 1) / 4` times in interavl `[L,R]`.  Let `val[i][k] = num[L][L + 2^k - 1]`, `k >= 2`.

Every `val[i][k]` has at most 4 elements, and we can calculate all `val[i][k]` for `0 <= i <= n` and `i + 2^k <= n` in `O(nlogn)` time and `O(nlogn)` memory.

Because for every interval `[L,R]` and `M1, M2` such that `L <= M < R it is obvious to see that` num[L][R] \subset num[L][M] \cup num[M + 1][R]`. Then` val[i][k] \subset val[i][k - 1] \cup val[i + 2^{k - 1} - 1][k - 1]`.

Let `t` as the greatest number such that `2^t <= R - L + 1` we can draw a conclusion that if `x \in [L,R]` appears not less than `(R - L + 1) / 2` times，x must in val[L][t] or val[R - 2^t + 1][R]。

This means it is sufficient to check the frequency of every element in `val[L][t] \cup val[R - 2^t - 1][t]`.

For every query `[L,R]` we can check every element in `O(logn)` time, so the total time is `O((m + n)logn)` where `n` is the element number of `A` and `m` is the query number.

If the question is to get the element appears exactly `(Ri-Li+1)/2 + 1` times (or more), it can be solve in a more simply way.